# Why XmlSerializer.Order do this

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

Can anybody explain why I am getting result below?

Class that should be instantiated:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class SampleClass
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 10)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 5)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

XML used for de-serialization:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SampleClass>
  <Foo>Test1</Foo>
  <Bar>Test2</Bar>
</SampleClass>
```

I see Foo = Test1 (correct) and Bar = null (not correct) in de-serialized class.

This is all about `Order` attribute. It is on purpose set to wrong values. Everything works fine if values are 0 and 1.

`Name` and `Order` criteria do not match for both fields but for some reason one field is de-serialized while second one does not. I would rather expect to see `Exception` or both values = null or both fields resolved and de-serialized.

Is there any explanation for that?

Comment: Did you mean to do this? `XmlSerializer(Order = 10)`

Comment: there is no XmlSerializer attribute.

Comment: So is your question: I'm deliberately doing it wrong but wondered why it's behaving differently to how I'd expect it to?

Comment: CodeIgnoto: Thanks. I fixed sample. It is XmlElementAttribute in my code.

Comment: You might want to look at this article which explains why this can happen and offers solutions - http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2009/01/interoperability-gotcha-order-of-xml.html

Answer (score 4):

You do see a serialization error actually.

It really comes down to design preference.  The developers decided that they didn't want to `except` and abort the entire deserialization process, but rather notify and continue.

Using your XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SampleClass>
  <Foo>Test1</Foo>
  <Bar>Test2</Bar>
</SampleClass>
```

Consider this code to deserialize it.

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SampleClass));

XmlDeserializationEvents events = new XmlDeserializationEvents();
events.OnUnknownAttribute = (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Unknown Attributed");
events.OnUnknownElement = (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Unknwon Element");
events.OnUnknownNode = (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Unknown Node");
events.OnUnreferencedObject = (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Unreferenced Object");

SampleClass cs_de = (SampleClass)xs.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)), events);

Debug.WriteLine(cs_de.Foo);
Debug.WriteLine(cs_de.Bar);
```

---

When I use the correct ordering.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
public string Foo { get; set; }
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
public string Bar { get; set; }
```

My output is

```
Foo
Bar
```

---

When I use the incorrect ordering.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 10)]
public string Foo { get; set; }
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 5)]
public string Bar { get; set; }
```

My output is

```
Unknown Node
Unknwon Element
Foo
```

---

So why does `Foo` print out?  Well my understanding is that `Order` is **NOT** the index.  The `Order`ing only specifies that `Foo` needs to appear before `Bar`, not that `Foo` needs to be the 10th element and `Bar` needs to be the 5th.  I think this makes the deserializer more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for help. This partially answers my question. Still looking for answer for another part  - Do you know why Foo is de-serialized even if it has wrong Order (the same as Bar). I would expect to see more consistent behavior (both field failed).

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski See my edit at the bottom.  I don't see how it's not consistent, just not what you expected.

Comment: Comment still does not explain the result. Both Elements have Order specified. Amount of fields in Class equals to amount of elements in XML. So result should be Bar = Test1 (because 5 is before 10) and Foo = Test2

Comment: But `Bar` can't be `Test1` because the element `<Bar>` has a value of `Test2`.  The element name corresponds with the property name in your class.

Comment: _But Bar can't be Test1_ - It should be according to Order. Test1 is value of first element in XML and Bar field has lowest Order value.

Comment: I can't agree with that.  It should be according to name *and* order.  If you removed the importance of the element->class name relationship, then there would be huge amounts of confusion.

Comment: _It should be according to name and order_ But it is not Name + Order for Foo. Foo should not be loaded because its Order refers to Bar. It is incontinent. It should be either error for both (if it is Name + Order) or data should be loaded for both (if only one criterion used).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18541/discussion-between-climbage-and-dmitry-harnitski)